# Extracting numeric values from a text array

Tags: php, arrays, string, int

How do I extract the numeric values from this array?

```
array (
  0 => '\'268',
  1 => '252',)
```

Just need the numbers stripped out, then I need to do some calculations.

Comment: What is your expected output ???

Comment: two strings or two integers, but just the number, no special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$source = array(
    0 => '\'268',
    1 => '252',
);

function strip($element)
{
    $matches = array();
    preg_match('#[0-9]+#', $element, $matches);
    return (int)reset($matches);
}

$result = array_map('strip', $source);

var_dump($result);
```

with result:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => int 268
  1 => int 252
```

Comment: thanks. I did it the long and hard way, but this looks much easier :). I used $tcx = (int)(trim($tc2[0],"'\'"); $tcy = (int)(trim($tc2[1],"'"); and that returns me two strings. I am assuming I don't need to do a var_dump($result) in the end code?